# How can I change Chrome's default search engine from the regional one to google.com without losing search suggestions?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to use google.com instead of google.com.hk as my default search engine in Chrome. I tried to use the 'custom search engine' option, but they all break search suggestions, not even something like

```
https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}
{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}
{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}
```

which includes parameters like `acceptedSuggestion` that seems to imply search suggestions being enabled. Search suggestions still don't work.

In addition, some websites suggest editing the Local State file under Chrome's setting folder. I already tried that, and it didn't work at all.

So, is there any way to use google.com as default search engine without breaking search suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to make search suggestions work, if you have a URL for fetching them.

1. Set the default search engine as you normally would, then exit Chrome completely
2. Open the Preferences file in your user profile
3. Look for `default_search_provider_data`
4. Under it, look for `template_url_data`
5. Under it, look for `suggestions_url`, or create it if it does not exist. Set it to a working URL, such as

   ```
   "suggestions_url": "https://clients1.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&hl={language}&q={searchTerms}"
   ```

   (Don't forget to add a comma at the end if there is another element following it.)
6. Also set `suggestions_url_post_params` as appropriate (it can be simply `""` for the above URL).

Comment: Is this method still valid? I cannot find `default_search_provider_data` in `Preferences`. I can see search engine settings in the `keywords` table in the file `Web Data`, but for some reason, when Chrome restarts, Chrome overwrites my edits.

Comment: @DamnVegetables: Pretty sure it broke at some point, but if you have a profile from an older version of Chrome that where you did this, it might still work after an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google.com search as your default search engine in the address bar and you're outside the United States, you may notice that the Google search engine is from a country-specific site (e.g. http://www.google.co.uk in the UK) rather than http://www.google.com. Google uses your computer's **IP address and cookies** to determine your location and the corresponding Google search engine to use.

If you'd rather use regular Google search in your address bar and force the result in English, follow these steps:

1. Go to http://www.google.com. If you're redirected to a
   country-specific site, click the Google.com in English link that's
   usually located at the bottom of the local Google site. Do a search.
   This action will save your preference for using the regular Google
   search engine in a cookie.
2. Close all your Google Chrome windows to exit the browser completely.
3. Open a new Google Chrome window.
4. The Google Chrome address bar should now be set to use the regular
   Google.com search as your search engine.

Answer (score -1):

Similarly, if Chrome or Opera for Windows changes your default search engine to a localized version,

a) force your web link or search engine to
https://www.google.com  (without any ....com.*), 
or specify 
https://www.google.com/ncr

b) Do a search directly from google.com, and make sure Chrome or Opera won't change the search back to a localized version.

c) Close all your Google Chrome or Opera windows to exit the browser completely.

d) Open a new Google Chrome or Opera window.

Now Chrome or Opera should stick to the original google.com search (at least for a while).

If not, try the other methods suggested here.